# Encoding Bytes in Python3

Tags: python

What type of codec is the best to encode binary files what are upload to an app write in Python 3?

Comment: What sort of files? Why do they need to be encoded?

Comment: Any, i am testing with an image and when i used the 'raw_unicode_escape' because the utf-8 duplicate the size of the file,but with this the file preserve the original size but says this when i open:(Quantization table 0x01 was not defined)

Comment: In Python 3 images should be nowhere near the string/unicode encoding. They should be uploaded, processed and saved as bytes. Why are you having to specify `raw_unicode_escape`? What is the type of the image when it was uploaded?

Comment: A normal image but i can't use the utf-8 because duplicate the size of the file and when i try to access give me this error:Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3f 0x3f), so i try to use another encode and this is that most close size give me but give me the that i post before.

Comment: This is part of the code what i want to save:
`ÿØÿà\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00ÿÛ\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07\t\t\x08\n\x0c\x14\r\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x19\x12\x13\x0f\x14\x1d\x1a\x1f\x1e\x1d\x1a\x1c\x1c $.\' ",#\x1c\x1c(7),01444\x1f\'9=82<.342ÿÛ\x00C\x01\t\t\t\x0c\x0b\x0c` and this is the error what gives me:
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x22 0x22) any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by *upload*? is it a web application and you are uploading a file using the web form?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, and the question isn't *entirely* clear, but if you need to encode a string of bytes to be saved somewhere, and for whatever reason you can't simply save the binary data, you should encode the string using the [`base64`](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) module. For example, say you have a long string of bytes (in this case, generated with `os.urandom(100)`:

```
import base64
import os
some_bytes = os.urandom(100)
print(repr(some_bytes))

some_bytes_base64 = base64.standard_b64encode(some_bytes).decode()
print(some_bytes_base64)
```

This prints something like the following:

```
b'\xd3\xa3\x0eT/L\xc6\x88\x98\xd0i\xbaa\xb2\x18\x1bx\xde\xf6Zq\xbe\xd9\xb4D\x19\x14\x91Z}wg?\x90\xd7f\xca\x1bxX\xa8\x99\xe6\xbb\xe0\x80\xa3\xc4\xb8\x1f\xfcp\xbc\x8d:/\xcfk\x01\xee\xc1\xde\xdc\xc3\xfa\x0e|7\x8eYt\xd1\x0b\x8a\x89\x9c^\xcf\xbc\\\x00_\x89dyb\x13\xa8\xdb\xba\xe3\x85X\x8d\x1a\x8bz\xe5\xfb\r'

06MOVC9MxoiY0Gm6YbIYG3je9lpxvtm0RBkUkVp9d2c/kNdmyht4WKiZ5rvggKPEuB/8cLyNOi/PawHuwd7cw/oOfDeOWXTRC4qJnF7PvFwAX4lkeWITqNu644VYjRqLeuX7DQ==
```

As you can see, the string has been properly encoded. The `decode()` method converts the byte literal that `base64.standard_b64encode` normally returns to a standard string. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2592818/869912) describes [byte literals](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)  well, in my opinion.

This should allow you to transmit a file, sequence of bytes, etc. without problems. (After all, isn't that was [`Base64 encoding`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is for?)