# ctypes_opencv TypeError on simple cvLoadImage

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, ctypes

I have an application that used to work. I recently had a full reinstall and tried to get the application working again, but I've run up against the problem in the title. I would appreciate any advice on next steps to investigate or try to get it working.

What happens:

```
ctypes_opencv.cvLoadImage('tmp.bmp', 1) #or a fully specified path

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python32_32bit\lib\site-packages\ctypes_opencv\highgui.py", line 289, in cvLoadImage
    z = pointee(_cvLoadImage(filename, iscolor))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

I tried using highgui.py's _cvLoadImage directly and got the same error. I don't think it's getting to the pointee() function.

I haven't been able to find anything I can pass to the function to make it not give me a TypeError. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't changed the code that worked previously.

The setup of this system:

- windows 7
- python 3.2.3 32bit (previous installation was 3.1.x 32bit but I couldn't find an installer for it this time)
- opencv 1.0 (I never had luck with ctypes_opencv and opencv > 1.0)
- ctypes_opencv 0.8.0

Comment: Double quotes instead of single quotes? `"tmp.bmp"`

Comment: good call. I tried it but it didn't change anything. I also tried a raw string r"tmp.bmp" but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaargh. I figured it out. ctypes_opencv apparently doesn't accept unicode strings. So using a [bytes literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-means) works.

```
ctypes_opencv.cvLoadImage(b'tmp.bmp', 1)
```

I hadn't worried about trying that yet since it used to work with my 3.1.x installation. Weren't all strings already unicode from the beginning of 3.x? I wrote the code myself so I am sure it hasn't been changed since I used it last.

Comment: if anybody can give a better explanation of where I went wrong, I'll mark yours as the solution :) Easy rep!