# Why does struct.pack seemingly return "0"?

Tags: python, byte

I have a number in integer form which I need to convert into 4 bytes and store it in a list. I am trying to use the struct module but am unable to get it to work:

```
struct.pack("i", 34);
```

This returns 0 when I am expecting the binary equivalent to be printed.

Expected output:

```
[0x00 0x00 0x00 0x22]
```

But `struct.pack` is returning empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3).hex() would convert string to hex format

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The output is returned as a *byte string*, and Python will print such strings as ASCII characters whenever possible:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("i", 34)
b'"\x00\x00\x00'
```

Note the quote at the start, that's ASCII codepoint 34:

```
>>> ord('"')
34
>>> hex(ord('"'))
'0x22'
>>> struct.pack("i", 34)[0]
34
```

Note that in Python 3, the `bytes` type is a *sequence of integers*, each value in the range 0 to 255, so indexing in the last example produces the integer value for the byte displayed as `"`.

For more information on Python byte strings, see [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean/24099252#24099252)

If you expected the ordering to be reversed, then you may need to [indicate a byte order](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

```
>>> struct.pack(">i",34)
b'\x00\x00\x00"'
```

where `>` indicates big-endian alignment.

Comment: how do I unpack to an integer

Comment: @DrDeo: using `struct.unpack()`, with a suitable format specifier and the bytes that hold the packed value.