# Python3 bytes to hex string

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have a bytes object:

```
a =  b'067b'
```

How do I get a string from it? Like this:

```
"067b"
```

I've tried:

```
In [3]: str(a)
Out[3]: "b'067b'"

In [4]: import codecs

In [5]: codecs.decode(a,'hex')
Out[5]: b'\x06{'

In [6]: import binascii

In [7]: binascii.b2a_hex(a)
Out[7]: b'30363762'

In [8]: binascii.hexlify(a)
Out[8]: b'30363762'
```

Is there *no way* to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply want to decode from ASCII here, your bytestring is *already* representing hexadecimal numbers, in ASCII characters:

```
>>> a = b'067b'
>>> a.decode('ascii')
'067b'
```

Everything you tried is interpreting the bytes as numeric data instead, either as hexadecimal numbers representing bytes or as bytes representing numeric data.

So your first attempt takes the value `06` as a hexadecimal number and turns that into the byte value `6`, and `7b` is turned into the byte value 123, which is the ASCII codepoint for the `{` character.

In your second attempt you are converting each byte to a hexadecimal representation of its numeric value. The `0` byte being interpreted as the integer number 48 (the ASCII codepoint for the `'0'` character), which is `30` in hexadecimal. `'6'` is 54, or `36` in hex, etc.

Comment: This works, but I don't see how `b'067b'` is ASCII. Isn't it really two bytes, '06' and '7b'? That'd give me indeed '\x06{' if taken as ASCII values. What's really going on here?

Comment: @MightyPork: no, it is **four** bytes. The characters `0`, `6`, `7` and `b`. The `b'...'` literal notation does not take hexadecimal characters, it takes ASCII characters.

Comment: @MightyPork: see the [literal notation specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals); if you meant to specify two bytes, you can use `b'\x06\x7b'` (e.g. use `\xhh` hex escapes), or use the `bytes()` function and pass in a sequence of integers: `bytes([0x06, 0x7b])`, using integers specified as hex literals.

Comment: I got this from `pyudev` and wanted to display it. I'm not building it. This was just the first time I've seen the b'blah' notation..

Comment: Right. Also see [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2592764) then. :-)

Answer (score 9):

The `bytes` representation can be confusing. `b'0607'` is not the same as `bytes([0x06,0x07]`). `b'0607'` is actually  4 bytes `[48,54,48,55]` where 48 is the ascii code for `0`,etc.

```
[x for x in b'0607'] 
[48, 54, 48, 55]
```

as such `b'0607'` is already an ascii string but represented as `bytes` if you want it to convert it to `str` you need to `b'0607'.decode("ascii")` (so that you construct a str from those bytes interpreting them like ascii code (as they are)).

In general, you convert `bytes` to hex string like this:

```
>>> a = binascii.hexlify(bytes([1,10,15,16,255]))
>>> a
b'010a0f10ff'
>>> type(a)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> b = a.decode("ascii")
>>> type(b)
<class 'str'>
```