# Python 3: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am slowly trying to convert an old python 2 code to Python 3, but I hit a roadblock with the following code:

```
seconds = functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*60+y,map(int,duration.split(":")))
```

Which gave me:

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

I changed it to:

```
b'functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*60+y,map(int,duration.split(":")))'
```

Which made the following line `rate = frames/seconds` give me this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'bytes'

So I tried to convert the original string to a float like this

```
seconds = float(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*60+y,map(int,duration.split(":"))))
```

But that just resulted in

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Can anyone please have a look?

```
import sys,os,re
import functools
from subprocess import *

if len(sys.argv)<=1:
  print ("usage: python oneinn.py filename frames")
  sys.exit(0)

try:
  fvideo = sys.argv[1]
  frames = float(sys.argv[2])
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Failed to parse parameters.\n")
  sys.exit(1)

output = Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", fvideo], stderr=PIPE).communicate()

# searching and parsing "Duration: 00:05:24.13," from ffmpeg stderr, ignoring the centiseconds
re_duration = re.compile("Duration: (.*?)\.")
duration = b're_duration.search(output[1]).groups()[0]'

seconds = float(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*60+y,map(int,duration.split(":"))))
rate = frames/seconds

print ("Duration = %s (%i seconds)" % (duration, seconds))
print ("Capturing one frame every %.1f seconds" % (1/rate))

output = Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", fvideo, "-r", str(rate), "-vcodec", "png", 'Preview-%d.png']).communicate()
```

Comment: Why are you doing: `b're_duration...'`? Looks really strange to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the use of the `b` prefix, look at this part of your code:

```
re_duration = re.compile("Duration: (.*?)\.")
duration = b're_duration.search(output[1]).groups()[0]'
```

Did you try printing `duration`? Because you'll get something like that:

```
>>> import re
>>> instr = 'Duration: 00:05:24.13,'
>>> re_duration = re.compile("Duration: (.*?)\.")
>>> duration = b're_duration.search(instr).groups()[0]'
>>> duration
b're_duration.search(instr).groups()[0]'
```

I doubt this is what you want, you are probably expecting:

```
'00:05:24'
```

Which can then be used in your `reduce` call.

You need to remove the `b'...'` around and simply do:

```
duration = re_duration.search(instr).groups()[0]
```

Full test code:

```
>>> import re, functools
>>> instr = 'Duration: 00:05:24.13,'
>>> re_duration = re.compile("Duration: (.*?)\.")
>>> duration = re_duration.search(instr).groups()[0]
>>> seconds = float(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*60+y,map(int,duration.split(":"))))
>>> seconds
324.0
```

The `b` prefix is used in python 3 to create `bytes` object, certainly not to "transform" any instruction, so doing `b'f(4)'` would just create and immediately delete a `bytes` object, same as if you'd done `'Hello World!'`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean) are some information about what the prefix `b` means in python 3.