# Kafka producer using python: TypeError: all produce message payloads must be null or type bytes

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I just started learning Python and Kafka.
This is the first example I tried to get started.
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5541

And I got an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "producer.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "producer.py", line 18, in main
    print_response(producer.send_messages(topic, msg))
  File "D:\Setups\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\simple.py", line 50, in send_messages
    topic, partition, *msg
  File "D:\Setups\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\base.py", line 379, in send_messages
    return self._send_messages(topic, partition, *msg)
  File "D:\Setups\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\base.py", line 396, in _send_messages
    raise TypeError("all produce message payloads must be null or type bytes")
TypeError: all produce message payloads must be null or type bytes
```

I've searched on google but I'm not quite sure what the problem is. 
Could anyone please give me some advice? 
Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient 

def print_response(response=None):
    if response:
        print('Error: {0}'.format(response[0].error))
        print('Offset: {0}'.format(response[0].offset))


def main():
    kafka = KafkaClient("10.2.5.53:9092")
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)

    topic = 'test'
    msg = 'Hello World'

    print_response(producer.send_messages(topic, msg))

    kafka.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: My guess would be that the error you're getting has to do with closing the kafka client before the producer actually responds, since it is an asynchronous process.

Comment: Take note that the Simple Producer and consumer APIS are deprecated as noted [here] (https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) (and they are simple implementations, but more complex to use!). You should use the high-level produced mentioned in that same page instead.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just realized from looking at the example you posted is that strings must be byte strings, prepended with a `b` character, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean)

Also, you're missing the try-except clause catches exceptions for when the server is not ready...