# New MD5 hash after changing a TXT file in Python

Tags: python, hash, md5

Good morning,
So, I created a MD5 hash from a TXT file. After changing the file content inserting new values, I tried to create a MD5 hash again, but the value didn't change. What could I do?

My code:

```
from hashlib import md5

open_file = open('N0003966.290', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
file = open_file.read().lower().rstrip('\n\r ').strip('\n\r')

m = md5()
m.update(b'file')
print(m.hexdigest())
```

I need to follow some requirements to build this hash, such as:

- The encoding rule must be 'ISO-8859-1'
- All the characters must be
  lowercase
- New line characters and carriage return characters must NOT be considered on hash building

Comment: Is that actually using the file object or the string 'file'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `update` on the string `'file'` rather than the content of the file. Do this instead:

```
from hashlib import md5

open_file = open('N0003966.290', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
file_content = open_file.read().lower().rstrip('\n\r ').strip('\n\r')

m = md5()
m.update(file_content.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
print(m.hexdigest())
```

Also note I replace your variable `file` by `file_content` (it is bad practice to override a built-in name).

Comment: I tried this code also, but when I don't put a 'b' after the variable name, I got the error:

TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: Ah yes, you need to encode properly your string. Try with my edit.

Comment: It's generating correctly a new hash after changing the txt file. The expect hash was not created, but I'l keep trying. Thank you @DevShark

Answer (score 1):

```
m.update(b'file')
```

This line is the problem. You're calling the function on the string 'file' represented as bytes (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean), for example, for more on what that means), not on the data within the file.

If you replace it with

```
m.update(file)
```

you should get the results you want (although, as DevShark points out, you should also change the name of that variable to something that doesn't already have its own meaning).

Answer (score 0):

```
m.update(file.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works in python 2.7 too.

```
from hashlib import md5

open_file = open('a.txt', 'r')
file = open_file.read().lower().rstrip('\n\r ').strip('\n\r')

m = md5()
m.update(file)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

`m.update(b'file')` is the place where you got error replace it with `m.update(file)`.