# Micropython strings

Tags: python, micropython

Using Micropython sockets I received a message which contained the following string:

b'xxx/yyy'

I don't know how the "b" got there, or what it is !!!

I can also enter this using an input statement

```
    x = input('Enter:')
>>> b'xxx/yyy'
    print(x)
>>> b'xxx/yyy'
    print (len(x))
>>> 7
    L = []
    L = x.split('/')
>>> TypeError: can't convert 'str' object to str implicitly
```

There must be a simple explanation to this, but I can not see it.

Is this some new type of variable ???

Comment: The b before the string shows that it is a byte string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string

Comment: Thank you, That explains it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean)

Answer (score 3):

It states that it is a utf-8 decoded string enclosed in a bytearray!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert this value.
So instead of:

`print(x)`

try

`print(x.decode('utf-8'))`