# hex attribute for bytes object in MicroPython

Tags: python, hex, byte, micropython

So, I'm porting a script that read a serial port using *pySerial* into micropython.

The serial reading works fine but I came across the issue that **MicroPython** seems to not support `.hex()` operations on bytes object.

On my Python 3.9 script, I receive bytes and then split them into a string spaced by `-` with the code

```
str(data_raw.hex('-'))
```

Now, from what I have understood MicroPython doesn't support it. I [have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027969/convert-byte-string-in-micropython) out this function but I would lose the option to separate the bytes with `-`

Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [binascii.hexlify](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) with a seperator:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(b"TEST", "-").decode()
'54-45-53-54'
```