# What's the difference between open('filepath', 'rb') and open(rb'filepath')? There's some encoding difference between them

Tags: python, file

What's the difference between `open('filepath', 'rb')` and `open(rb'filepath')`? The second gives me the following Unicode related error when I try to hash the contents:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Here's my sample code

```
import hashlib
f1 = open('findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py', 'rb')
f2 = open(rb'findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py')

hashlib.sha512()
hasher.update(f1)
hasher.update(f2) #error comes up here
```

I am on Python 3.6.0

Comment: One is passing a second parameter to `open` the other creates a raw binary string and pass it to `open` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`open('findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py', 'rb')` will open the file `findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py` for read mode (`r`) with binary I/O (`b`).

In `rb'findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py'`, the `r` prefix marks the string literal as raw (which doesn't do anything in this particular case), while the `b` prefix marks it as [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592764/501250), which means that the resulting object is a `bytes` object, *not* a `str` object.

`open()` doesn't care about this; it will just convert the first operand to a string.  However, because the *second* parameter (the file open mode) is omitted, the file is opened with the default mode, which is `'r'` (not `'rb'`) and therefore is opened for read access in text-mode.

So these three expressions are effectively equivalent:

- `open(rb'findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py')`
- `open('findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py')`
- `open('findMaxConsecutiveOnes.py', 'r')`

A file opened in text-mode will return Unicode `str` objects from read operations, while a file opened in binary-mode will return `bytes` objects.  The `hashlib` hasher functions can only hash bytes; they don't know or care about Unicode strings. This makes sense because the *hash functions themselves* only operate on bytes. That's the source of the error.

Opening the file in binary-mode (the first example you give) circumvents this problem by not attempting to decode characters at all.  It just reads raw bytes, and `hashlib` is happy.  (It also doesn't waste any energy trying to decode characters that it would otherwise just have to re-encode later.)