# Confusing output from executing Php in Python

Tags: php, python

Why I get output with *b* and *''*?

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['php', 'index.php'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

**Output => b'Hello'**

In Php I have just echo().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean)

Answer (score 0):

`result.stdout` is a `bytes` object, and the `bytes.__str__()` methods returns its representation (see [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)).

Try with `print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))` to decode the bytes as UTF-8.

Suggested reading: [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)