# How to compare hashed password to Input() in Python?

Tags: python, bcrypt

**Goal:**

Currently learning how to encrypt passwords using Python.

**Current code:**

```
import bcrypt

passwd = b'False'

salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(passwd, salt)

x = input()

print(hashed == bcrypt.hashpw(x, hashed))
```

**Problem:**

I might be doing this wrong, need a bit of guidance how to achieve this correctly.

How can I insert a input value between the apostrophes for`b''`? That's where the password will be and compared to the Hashed one.

**This is what I have tried (Also, Im I on the right lines?):**

```
x = b'%s' % (input())
```

**Output on CMD**

```
    x = b'%s' % (input())
TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
```

**Goal**

I am trying to compare input to the hashed password.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `checkpw` method? Also note that in your second call to `hashpw` you're using the whole previous hashed password as the "salt", so even if `x == passwd` the hashes won't match; using the built-in functionality would avoid this, as it gets the appropriate salt from the existing hash.

Comment: @jonrsharpe never heard of it - I'll have a read of what it is. x == passwd output is 'true'. If I use x = b'False'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand what `b''` does before using it, and that would allow you to look for a solution in the right direction.

The answer is: it indicates that what you're assigning is a string bytes literal. That basically means that you have a bunch of bytes as your data. (See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean))

Once you know that you can search how to convert a string to bytes in Python, which leads you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

So, the answer to your initial question (and yes, you should use `checkpw`), is:

`print(hashed == bcrypt.hashpw(x.encode('utf-8'), hashed))`