# Scapy load into readable string python 3.7

Tags: python

`print(scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load)` gives hex string. How to convert into readable string?

Comment: No, that’s not a hex string. It’s the representation of the bytes value, see [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592764)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
print(bytearray.fromhex(scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load).decode())
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: can you please provide the value of Raw. I also updated my answer, please see if it works.

Comment: here is my complete raw bytes https://pastebin.com/Czzu2jpA

Comment: It's not hex, it's bytes. It's not readable and will never be

Comment: Scapy raw data is already a bytes value.