# sqlite3.OperationalError: User defined function raised exception

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to get the md5sum of a table field in sqlite3 using a User-defined function.

[Edit] The code shown below was tried after reading documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function

On python 3.8, The following code throws `sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception`

How do I fix this ?

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib


def md5sum(text):
    return hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest()


with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as conn:
    conn.executescript("""
        CREATE TABLE project(name);
        INSERT INTO project(name) VALUES ('test');
    """)
    conn.create_function("md5", 1, md5sum)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # cursor.execute("SELECT name from project")
    cursor.execute("SELECT md5(name) from project") # Throws error
    print(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in the example from the doc that it is sending `b"foo"` to the function (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean) for more info). Try casting `name` as BLOB in the SELECT and see if that changes the result. ie `md5(CAST (name as BLOB))`