# How to add a character before a string?

Tags: python, string

I am new and I'm trying to insert a character before a string.

If I have a string like so:

```
'wB0JSYuEUshUkgpKi8TRTwv/EABgBAQADAQAAAAAAA'
```

I want to add b before the string but not part of the string-like so:

```
b'wB0JSYuEUshUkgpKi8TRTwv/EABgBAQADAQAAAAAAA'
```

Here's what I tried:

```
test = 'b' + words[1]
test
```

but this obviously returns the `b` within the string, which is not what I want.

Comment: What's the use case? The `b` isn't part of the string itself, but a marker for a *literal* of type `bytes`. If you just need a `bytes` value, use `test = words.encode()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `b` is not part of the string, it's a special syntax in Python 3.x to indicate that it's a `bytes` literal (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592764/201359)). If you want to convert a "normal" string into a `bytes` literal, do this:

```
st = 'abc'
bl = st.encode()

bl
=> b'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But assuming words is a list of strings, and index 1 = `'wB0JSYuEUshUkgpKi8TRTwv/EABgBAQADAQAAAAAAA'` you could `print(f'b {words[1]}')`

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure if OP was asking to literally insert a character, or to convert to bytes

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion here. In python "" is a string and b"" is a byte string. These are completely different objects. They can be converted to one another, but they are not the same thing. You can't add "b to a string". Essentially a byte string b"" is a string of the bytes that generate a string, and a string is well the string. For example,

```
x = 'STRING'   #The string itself. 
y = x.encode() #The bytes for the string. Note that ascii bytes are written in ascii. 

a = 'MyName®'  #The string itself.
b = a.encode() #The bytes for the string. The last character takes two non-ascii bytes. 
c = b.decode() #Covert the bytes back to a string.
```