# An undefined letter appears?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqgis

I'm running the following snippet. For some reason, which I don't get, a "b" appears in the path when stating the location of a file.

```
# %% Definitions

path_root = normpath(r'G:\\Dropbox\\temp\\')
path_start = normpath(r'G:\\Dropbox\\temp\\worklayers\\')
path_temp = normpath(r'G:\\Dropbox\\temp\\templayers\\')
path_temp2 = normpath(r'G:\\Dropbox\\temp\\temp2layers\\')
path_end = normpath(r'G:\\Dropbox\\temp\\resultlayers\\')
path_doc = normpath(r'G:\\Dropbox\\Documents\\')

directory = os.fsencode(path_start)

df = pd.read_csv(path_doc+'\\DEM_masterfile.csv')

slope_list = [4, 4.9, 5.9, 7.1, 8.2, 10, 11.8, 13.8, 15.7, 17.9, 20.6, 25]
aspect_list_1 = [[0, 15], [15,30], [30, 45], [45, 60], [60, 75], [75, 90], [90, 105], [105, 120], [120, 135], [135, 150], [150, 165], [165, 180]]
aspect_list_2 = [[180, 195], [195, 210], [210, 225], [225, 240], [240, 255], [255, 270], [270, 285], [285, 300], [300, 315], [315, 330], [330, 345], [345, 360]]

# %% Generating the slope and aspect vector files from the DEM raster

for number in os.listdir(directory):
    
    processing.run("native:slope", {'INPUT':path_start+'\\'+str(number),'Z_FACTOR':1,'OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'slope_'+str(number)})
    processing.run("native:aspect", {'INPUT':path_start+'\\'+str(number),'Z_FACTOR':1,'OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_'+str(number)})
```

When running this the following error appears `Could not load source layer for INPUT: G:\Dropbox\temp\worklayers\b'hej0.tif' not found`

Where is that b in the error message coming from?? `G:\Dropbox\temp\worklayers\b'hej0.tif'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.fsencode(path_start)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsencode) returns an instance of [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).
Then `os.listdir(directory)` returns a list of `bytes` because you gave `bytes` as its argument.

The `b'...'` is the result of calling `str(...)` on an instance of `bytes`.
I'm not sure what the reason was for using `os.fsencode` in this code and ending up with `bytes`.

To convert a `bytes` to a string, you could use [`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) or [`os.fsdecode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsdecode), the reverse of `os.fsencode`.

Comment: The reason I use {os.fsencode} is because I want to list the files in a path. 
I guess there's two options; turn them into strings or use another method of listing the files in that path.

Thanks for clearing it out!