# How can I fix duplicate targets with Cmake?

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I am currently trying to install `gr-matchstiq` from [GitHubLink](https://github.com/epiqsolutions/gr-matchstiq) and am having trouble. The code no longer conforms to CMake's standards.

Specifically, cmake 2.6 intoduced the policy that logical target names must be unique (see: [CMP0002](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0002.html)). However, the target 'ALL' is used repeatedly. I believe this is so, because of the error I get:

```
$ cmake -Wno-dev ../
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:115 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "ALL" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory "/home/me/Projects/gr-matchstiq/swig".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:214 (GR_UNIQUE_TARGET)
  python/CMakeLists.txt:31 (GR_PYTHON_INSTALL)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:115 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "ALL" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory "/home/me/Projects/gr-matchstiq/swig".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:214 (GR_UNIQUE_TARGET)
  apps/CMakeLists.txt:22 (GR_PYTHON_INSTALL)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/me/Projects/gr-matchstiq/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/me/Projects/gr-matchstiq/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The code at cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:115 is:

```
add_custom_target(${_target} ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})
```

The code at cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:214 is:

```
GR_UNIQUE_TARGET("pygen" ${python_install_gen_targets})
```

I don't have almost no experience with cmake, so am uncertain which fix is safest, either

1. In root CMakelists.txt file, add line (Note: This didn't work, but maybe I did something wrong):

   `set_property(GLOBAL ALLOW_DUPLICATE_TARGETS TRUE)`
2. Change the 'ALL' cmake/Modules/GrPython.cmake:115 to something like 'ALL_PY' - i.e.

   `add_custom_target(${_target} ALL_PY DEPENDS ${ARGN})`
3. Somehow modify the GR_UNIQUE_TARGET function (lines 107-116 of GrPython.cmake):

> ```
> ########################################################################
> # Create an always-built target with a unique name
> # Usage: GR_UNIQUE_TARGET(<description> <dependencies list>)
> ########################################################################
> function(GR_UNIQUE_TARGET desc)
>     file(RELATIVE_PATH reldir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
>     execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "import re, hashlib
> unique = hashlib.md5('${reldir}${ARGN}').hexdigest()[:5]
> print(re.sub('\\W', '_', '${desc} ${reldir} ' + unique))"
>     OUTPUT_VARIABLE _target OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
>     add_custom_target(${_target} ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})
> endfunction(GR_UNIQUE_TARGET)
> ```

Or, is there something else I should do?

PS - One other fix I needed to make was in lines 95-102:

```
########################################################################
# Sets the python installation directory GR_PYTHON_DIR
########################################################################
execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "
from distutils import sysconfig
print (sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=True, prefix=''))
" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GR_PYTHON_DIR OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

Originally, the Python print statement did not have the "(" & ")" req'd by Python3)

PPS - I have no idea how to either handle or find the Type Errors, so will deal with them later.

Comment: It looks as if the variable `_target` is never set so the line `add_custom_target(${_target} ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})` collapses to `add_custom_target(ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})` . Print `_target` to verify and find out why it's never set, that's the root cause. BTW, `ALL` is an invalid target name on (more recent versions of) CMake, anyway.

Comment: @Friedrich - Thx. This code is 9-10 yrs old, with the exception of a .cc &.h file that are 7 yrs old. I suppose whatever else I do, I'll need to change the ALL trgts to some other name.

Comment: No. You need to make sure `_target` is not unset. Don't touch anything else. The value of `_target` will be the name of your target. Take a look at [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html). The `ALL` is supposed to be in there as *second* argument.

Comment: what version of Python 2 do you have installed on your machine and how exactly did you install it?

Comment: @Friedrich - I grep'd and only found two uses of `_target`. Both were in the GR_UNIQUE_TARGET function in my option #3. As you surmised, when I add `message(_target="${_target}")`, I see that `_target` has no value (i.e. _target = ""). Can I just assign a string value to it? Could this code ever have worked???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Go with option 3: you need to hash a `bytes` object

Prefix the string to be hashed with a `b`:

```py
unique = hashlib.md5(b'${reldir}${ARGN}').hexdigest()[:5]
```

#### Comments recap

CMake bails out with an error because multiple targets named "ALL" are defined. This is owed to the line

```
add_custom_target(${_target} ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})
```

where `_target` is an unset variable. So the line becomes (I'll denote the unset variable with the pseudo-symbol `<unset>`):

```
add_custom_target(<unset> ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})
```

and CMake only sees:

```
add_custom_target(ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})
```

According to the signature of [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), the first argument is the target's name while an optional `ALL` as second argument will cause the target always to be built. Without the first arg, `ALL` becomes first and causes the error we see. This is only a secondary error, let's dig deeper.

The custom target is added in function `GR_UNIQUE_TARGET` and this function is called repeatedly. In reply to *"can I just assign a string value to it?"* - No. Setting a static string will not work and just toss you back into your *target name not unique* condition.

To give each target a unique name, the original developers came up with a tiny Python snippet to generate a hash from the input files and generate a target name from this.

#### Taking a look at the Python code

I copied the Python code and ran it and was promptly greeted by the following error:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

because [Python 3's `hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) expects a unicode `bytes` objects. If you give it one, either by [prefixing a `b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean) or calling the `encode` method, the code works. Try out the following function (note the added `b`):

```
function(GR_UNIQUE_TARGET desc)
    file(RELATIVE_PATH reldir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
    execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "import re, hashlib
unique = hashlib.md5(b'${reldir}${ARGN}').hexdigest()[:5]
print(re.sub('\\W', '_', '${desc} ${reldir} ' + unique))"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE _target OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    add_custom_target(${_target} ALL DEPENDS ${ARGN})
endfunction(GR_UNIQUE_TARGET)
```

In reply to *"could it ever have worked?"* - Yes, I do think so. Maybe not the most elegant way to do it and it looks a bit like one of these *if your only tool is a hammer ...* solutions (I don't have a better idea in my drawer, however) but definitely workable. Coincidentally, [Python 2.7's `hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hashlib.html) was happy with a `str` object so it would have worked back then.